# Access 2007 SQL query to ignore 0 value

Tags: sql-server, ms-access-2007

Im trying to build by day report at the moment the code im using works but nnot to what i need it to do.

```
SELECT Notices.Promoter, 
Sum(IIf([Notices].[Type]='GRANT PERMIT' Or [Notices].[Type]='GRANT VARIATION' Or [Notices].[Notice Type]='GRANT PAA',1,0)) AS Granted, 
Sum(IIf([Notices].[Type]='REFUSE    APPLICATION',1,0)) AS Refused, 
Sum(IIf([Notices].[Status]='Deemed',1,0)) AS Deemed, 
Sum(IIf([Notices].[Error]<>"" And Notices.[Category]<>"Observation" And Notices.[Category]<>"S.74 Overrun",1,0)) AS [Potential Penalty]
FROM Notices
WHERE (((Notices.[Day Of Week])=[TempVars]![DayReport]))
GROUP BY Notices.Promoter;
```

the tempVar [DayReport] is the day of the week mon,tue,wed.... sun
and the code outputs this

```
Promoter | Granted | Refused | Deemed | Potential Penalty
Name     |   0     |    0    |    0   |   0
Name2    |   3     |    0    |    0   |   0
Name3    |   4     |    2    |    1   |   0
Name4    |   0     |    1    |    1   |   0
Name5    |   1     |    0    |    0   |   0
```

What i want is it to not show the Promoter that has all 0's in the fields like this

```
Promoter | Granted | Refused | Deemed | Potential Penalty
Name2    |   3     |    0    |    0   |   0
Name3    |   4     |    2    |    1   |   0
Name4    |   0     |    1    |    1   |   0
Name5    |   1     |    0    |    0   |   0
```

As im not sure about how to go about this i thought i would put it to the wonderful people of Stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  *
FROM
(
    SELECT  Notices.Promoter, 
            Sum(IIf([Notices].[Type]='GRANT PERMIT' Or [Notices].[Type]='GRANT VARIATION' Or [Notices].[Notice Type]='GRANT PAA',1,0)) AS Granted, 
            Sum(IIf([Notices].[Type]='REFUSE    APPLICATION',1,0)) AS Refused, 
            Sum(IIf([Notices].[Status]='Deemed',1,0)) AS Deemed, 
            Sum(IIf([Notices].[Error]<>"" And Notices.[Category]<>"Observation" And Notices.[Category]<>"S.74 Overrun",1,0)) AS [Potential Penalty]
    FROM    Notices
    WHERE   (((Notices.[Day Of Week])=[TempVars]![DayReport]))
    GROUP   BY Notices.Promoter
) s
WHERE   Promoter <> 0
        Refused <> 0 AND 
        Deemed <> 0 AND 
        [Potential Penalty] <> 0
```

**UPDATE 1**

```
SELECT  Notices.Promoter, 
        Sum(IIf([Notices].[Type]='GRANT PERMIT' Or [Notices].[Type]='GRANT VARIATION' Or [Notices].[Notice Type]='GRANT PAA',1,0)) AS Granted, 
        Sum(IIf([Notices].[Type]='REFUSE    APPLICATION',1,0)) AS Refused, 
        Sum(IIf([Notices].[Status]='Deemed',1,0)) AS Deemed, 
        Sum(IIf([Notices].[Error]<>"" And Notices.[Category]<>"Observation" And Notices.[Category]<>"S.74 Overrun",1,0)) AS [Potential Penalty]
FROM    Notices
WHERE   (((Notices.[Day Of Week])=[TempVars]![DayReport]))
GROUP   BY Notices.Promoter
HAVING  Sum(IIf([Notices].[Type]='GRANT PERMIT' Or [Notices].[Type]='GRANT VARIATION' Or [Notices].[Notice Type]='GRANT PAA',1,0)) <> 0 AND
        Sum(IIf([Notices].[Type]='REFUSE    APPLICATION',1,0)) <> 0 AND
        Sum(IIf([Notices].[Status]='Deemed',1,0)) <> 0 AND
        Sum(IIf([Notices].[Error]<>"" And Notices.[Category]<>"Observation" And Notices.[Category]<>"S.74 Overrun",1,0)) <> 0
```

Comment: see my update, i don't know if alias is supported on having cluase because in mysql, it will.